# How can a fp with higher mantissa represent a smaller number?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I love `FP`; every time I think to had got it, I understand to know nothing about it :)

[This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0c49afbf93eb69f) is an example that I don't understand. I sum 8 time the same number (`0.1`) and I print the result, of both sum and "original":

```
std::cout.precision(100);

int numIteration = 8;
double step = 0.1;
double sum = 0.0;

for(int i = 0; i < numIteration; i++) {
    sum += step;
}

std::cout << "orig stored as " << numIteration / 10.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << " sum stored as " << sum << std::endl;
```

`0.1` is stored as `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`, and I expect that after 8 sum, it will be stored bigger or equal of `0.8`, which is stored as `0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125`.

But the result shock me. In fact after 8 sum, the result is `0.79999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125`, which is smaller.

Also, if I check the binary output of both, I can see that the sum is "higher" than the "original":

```
0.8 stored as binary 0 01111111110 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001 // smaller
sum stored as binary 0 01111111110 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 // higher
```

But `0.79999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125` < `0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125`.

Can you shine me?

**EDIT**: sorry to everybody, I had a mistake on copy/paste the binary. They were correct.

Comment: You're assuming rounding up on every addition.   Rounding can be up or down.

Comment: What platform are you using, and what compiler flags are you using?  On intel at least, "sum" may be calculated in 80 bit precision rather than 64-bit.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I'm using that http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ platform! Just a test...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [IEEE floating-point rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) happens after every arithmetic operation. And the rounding could go up or down.
If you print the value of `sum` at every iteration you should see:

```
sum is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
sum is 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
sum is 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
sum is 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
sum is 0.5
sum is 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
sum is 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
sum is 0.79999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125
```

You assume that the rounding could only go up. But, since *"Round to nearest, ties to even"* is the default rounding-mode in IEEE 754, the nearest binary-representable value is picked at every iteration, therefore the result is not necessary larger than `0.8`.

On the other hand

```
std::cout << 0.1 * 8.0 << std::endl;
```

Will produce the expected

```
0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

**Update:** as @Evg mentioned in the comment, floating-point rounding direction can be changed with [`std::fesetround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround).

Comment: Rounding mode can be changed. For example, with `std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);`, `sum = 0.80..038...`.

Comment: @Evg: can't emulate that `std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);, sum = 0.80..038...` beahvour here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49be969a6851768f

Comment: @markzzz I'm not sure why, but disabling optimization makes it work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d54c76d49b3d8d28

Comment: @markzzz, not all compilers support it and pragma syntax can vary. Msvs: use `#pragma fenv_access (on)`, gcc: instead of `#pragma` use command line option `-frounding-math`, clang: I don't know.

Comment: In fact, this can happen in any number system, e.g. 0.56 + 0.56 = 1.12, but rounded back to two signficant digits, just 1.1.

Comment: @markzzz The reason it doesn't work in that example is because the compiler optimizes away the loop: https://godbolt.org/z/bRWh9n (note the two constants at the top of the assembly). That's also why you can get it to happen by disabling optimizations.

Comment: @AMA Optimizations fold the loop into a constant calculated at compile time. [Compile time expressions are not affected by `std::fesetround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round).

Comment: So basically is compiler that tells settings to the FPU? It got this power? :D

Answer (score 2):

Your binary representations are wrong. The correct ones are:

```
sum = 0.79999999999999993 ... = 
0b0011111111101001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001

numIteration / 10.0 = 0.80000000000000004... = 
0b0011111111101001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

Comment: Damn you are right! Now re-looking them I see I did a mistake on copy/paste. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is a problem when you add a small increment to a large sum.  There is not enough precision to store the full result, and some significance is lost.  By the last iteration of the loop you have started to run into this.

For a sufficiently large sum and small increment, the sum may not change at all.

Comment: The accepted answer showed the counterintuitive result of `0.5 + (0.1 + epsilon) < 0.6` happening halfway through the loop. I would not really call this a "small increment to a large sum" (although you are technically right about loss of precision).

Comment: @MaxLanghof By the time you reach the mid-point, you have already got two bits hanging off the end of the increment.

Comment: **Any** (non-subnormal) floating point addition has at least one bit hanging off the end: Either the exponents are the same (in which case the sum's exponent must be higher because both mantissas start with an implied leading 1 so you get a carry) thus tossing the least significant bit, or the exponents are already different and you lose bits from the one with the lower exponent. So again - technically loss of precision is correct. But that has nothing to do with "small increment to large sum".

Answer (score 1):

While AMA's answer is correct in that rounding happens after every addition, the same surprises can happen even for just a single operation (including multiplication):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     const auto val1 = 0.3444444444444444
              , val2 = 0.34444444444444442;
     std::cout << (2*val1) << '\n'
               << (2*val2) << '\n';
}
```

(Unless otherwise mentioned, I assume IEEE doubles with standard rounding behavior.)

The first line will show 0.6888888888888888 (if you trust me to do the counting for you, it's 15x 4 in the input, and 15x 8 in the output) with no surprises. We'd assume that the second line shows either an additional digit, hopefully somewhat near 4, or that the result is unchanged.

In reality, however, the second line will show 0.688888888888888**9**. That's a surprise, how can a 4 on the last digit be rounded **up** on the next higher digit? This contradicts our notion that inequalities are maintained when a positive scaling factor is applied on both sides. I.e. since 2 < 2.5, then 2*2 < 2*2.5, then 4<5. This means, since it would take a last digit of 5 to round up (in the decimal system) in `2*val2`, that `val2` would intuitively have to be at least 0.3444444444444444**25** for upward rounding.

The problem here is that every number system has different rounding of inputs and outputs. In fact, no rounding even occurs in binary as a result of the multiplication itself, however rounding occurs in both number system conversions. Binary representations of the inputs:

0.01011000001011011000001011011000001011011000001011001 (`val1`)
0.01011000001011011000001011011000001011011000001011011 (`val2`)

A multiplication by 2 is just a left shift by 1, of course, in binary, which includes floating point (at least if we ignore the possibility of overflow), so the outputs are:

0.10110000010110110000010110110000010110110000010110010 (`2*val1`)
0.10110000010110110000010110110000010110110000010110110 (`2*val2`)

The latter converts back to 0.688888888888888**88395**… (note there is an additional 8 now), which is correctly rounded to 0.6888888888888888**9**.

In this particular case, the original cause of the surprising behavior is that `val2` actually becomes:

0.3444444444444444**419772821675**

also with an additional 4 which replaces the trailing 2 we entered, and that, when doubled, causes upward rounding to occur in decimal.